# sed command to delete the lines with pattern "></" and "/>"

Tags: sed

I am trying to use the sed command to delete lines in a file with the pattern `"></"` and `"/>"`

```
sed -i '/\/>/d' $1       --> Works fine
sed -i '/>/</\//d' $1    --> Error=>   sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `<'
```

Can anyone please suggest a solution for the second one ?

and if I can combine both pattern checks in one sed command ?

Comment: As you have strings with `/`, you can consider using another `sed` delimiter: `sed -i 's#something#other thing#g` is also accepted.

Comment: double escape `\\`. it should be escaped for shell, before it gets in regexp.

Comment: I think, the command  sed -i 's#something#other thing#g  is for replacing the pattern 'something' with 'other thing'.       But my requirement is to remove the lines containing the patterns.       Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

To delete lines containing the pattern you could do:

```
$ grep -ve '></' -e '/>' file
1
2
3
```

Or to delete just the patterns:

```
$ sed -r 's%(></)|(/>)%%g' file
1
 and 
2

3
foo  bar
```

Where the input file is:

```
$ cat file
1
></ and />
2
></
3
foo /> bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sed -i '#></|/>#d' $1
```

You should consider using a different separator than `/` e.g. `#` when you have `/` in search pattern

Comment: Your precedence is incorrect `></|/>` you need brackets `(></)|(/>)` currently you deleting lines containing the pattern `></>` as `/|/` is the same as just `/`.

Comment: I think @sudo_O is right... you need to make sure that "the things on either side of the OR symbol" are the whole expression you want to delete.

Comment: ya i found some problem with the above code.Try this `sed -i '/><\//d';/\/>/d' $1`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got it working. Code is as below.
sed -i '//>/d' $1
sed -i '/><//d' $1
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this out. I found his working fine

```
sed -i '/><\//d';/\/>/d' $1
```

It will delete all the lines contains `></` and `/>`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i -e '\#></#d' -e '\#/>#d' file
```